# spread html in multiple lines javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put the below html code in my javascript function. I don't want to put it all next to each other. Is it possible to the code in the same way as how it is in html?
Code:

```
    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="Gallery2" class="gallery-page">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Second Gallery</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">   

            <ul class="gallery">

                <li><a href="images/full/010.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/010.jpg" alt="Image 010" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/full/011.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/011.jpg" alt="Image 011" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/full/012.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/012.jpg" alt="Image 012" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/full/013.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/013.jpg" alt="Image 013" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/full/014.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/014.jpg" alt="Image 014" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/full/015.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/015.jpg" alt="Image 015" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/full/016.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/016.jpg" alt="Image 016" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/full/017.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/017.jpg" alt="Image 017" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/full/018.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/018.jpg" alt="Image 018" /></a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>&copy; 2011 Code Computerlove</h4>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Updated, seems like Javascript does support multi lines by adding a backslash ( \ ) as the last character in the line, you can't even have a space bar behind it, because then it won't cancel the line break.

```
    var str = '<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="Gallery2" class="gallery-page"> \
    <div data-role="header">  \
        <h1>Second Gallery</h1> \
    </div> \
    <div data-role="content"> \  
        <ul class="gallery"> \
            <li><a href="images/full/010.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/010.jpg" alt="Image 010" /></a></li> \
            <li><a href="images/full/011.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/011.jpg" alt="Image 011" /></a></li> \
            <li><a href="images/full/012.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/012.jpg" alt="Image 012" /></a></li> \
            <li><a href="images/full/013.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/013.jpg" alt="Image 013" /></a></li> \
            <li><a href="images/full/014.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/014.jpg" alt="Image 014" /></a></li> \
            <li><a href="images/full/015.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/015.jpg" alt="Image 015" /></a></li> \
            <li><a href="images/full/016.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/016.jpg" alt="Image 016" /></a></li> \
            <li><a href="images/full/017.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/017.jpg" alt="Image 017" /></a></li> \
            <li><a href="images/full/018.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/018.jpg" alt="Image 018" /></a></li> \
        </ul> \
    </div> \
    <div data-role="footer"> \
        <h4>&copy; 2011 Code Computerlove</h4> \
    </div> \
</div>';
```

Or use a HTML template and load it into a DIV (using jQuery)

```
$("#div").load("/html_template.html");
```

Comment: using \ javascript *does* allow multiline strings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript/805755#805755

Comment: Wow, I'm using javascript for a few years now, and never seen that before, that's great.

Comment: Thanks, That helped a great deal. :)

Answer (score 10):

You can kind of do this:

```
var myHtml = [
 'firstline',
 'second line',
 'third line'].join("\n");
```

So pretty much you still need to break up the code some how.

An alternative (if the code is going to be large) would be to store in a HTML file and when you need, retrieve it quickly with `$.get` and possibly cache it somewhere in a variable.

```
$.get('snippet.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

I think this is actually a pretty good idea as modifying that snippet will be much easier.

Answer (score 4):

Really old question, but I don't find this syntax a lot, so I'll just leave this here, as to me it is the most readable.

```
var html = '' +
    '    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="Gallery2" class="gallery-page">' +
    '' +
    '        <div data-role="header">' +
    '            <h1>Second Gallery</h1>' +
    '        </div>' +
    '' +
    '        <div data-role="content">' +
    '' +
    '            <ul class="gallery">' +
    '' +
    '                <li><a href="images/full/010.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/010.jpg" alt="Image 010" /></a></li>' +
    '                <li><a href="images/full/011.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/011.jpg" alt="Image 011" /></a></li>' +
    '                <li><a href="images/full/012.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/012.jpg" alt="Image 012" /></a></li>' +
    '                <li><a href="images/full/013.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/013.jpg" alt="Image 013" /></a></li>' +
    '                <li><a href="images/full/014.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/014.jpg" alt="Image 014" /></a></li>' +
    '                <li><a href="images/full/015.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/015.jpg" alt="Image 015" /></a></li>' +
    '                <li><a href="images/full/016.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/016.jpg" alt="Image 016" /></a></li>' +
    '                <li><a href="images/full/017.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/017.jpg" alt="Image 017" /></a></li>' +
    '                <li><a href="images/full/018.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/thumb/018.jpg" alt="Image 018" /></a></li>' +
    '' +
    '            </ul>' +
    '' +
    '        </div>' +
    '' +
    '        <div data-role="footer">' +
    '            <h4>&copy; 2011 Code Computerlove</h4>' +
    '        </div>' +
    '' +
    '    </div>';
```

With a simple shell command to generate this from an html file:

```
cat myfile.html | sed "s/'/\\'/g" | sed "$ ! s/^.*$/'\0' +/g" | sed "$ s/^.*$/'\0';/"
```

---

Update: With ES6, simply use backticks:

```
const html = `
  <div>
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
`;
```

Answer (score 3):

Generating html from javascript directly ties logic and presentation together. It also garbles your code.

You can use a javascript templating engine like [pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) to get a clear separation of logic and presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but right now (2023) it is posible to use  ` instead ' or " for inserting of multiple html lines in javascript